# Creating an ID variable based on 3 common variables in R

Tags: r, variables, sorting, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (below) which is a subset of my full dataset. I need to define the same ID for each entries with the same LAT/LONG and landed date. I previously ordered LANDEDDATE from the earliest to latest date.

```
 > dput(df2)
structure(list(LATITUDE = c(43.35, 43.35, 43.35, 43.35, 43.35, 
43.35, 43.35, 43.35, 43.5166, 43.5166, 43.5166, 43.5166, 43.5166, 
43.5166, 43.5166, 42.9833, 42.9833, 42.9833, 42.9666, 42.9666
), LONGITUDE = c(-60.6163, -60.6165, -60.7167, -60.7166, -60.7163, 
-60.716, -60.7169, -60.7166, -59.9169, -59.9168, -59.9169, -59.9166, 
-59.9166, -59.916, -59.916, -61.8333, -61.8333, -61.8333, -61.9161, 
-61.9161), LANDEDDATE = structure(c(11171, 11171, 11183, 11183, 
11183, 11183, 11183, 11183, 11192, 11192, 11192, 11192, 11192, 
11192, 11192, 11210, 11210, 11210, 11210, 11210), class = "Date"), 
    sppCODE = c(251L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 
    251L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 256L, 251L, 256L, 252L, 251L, 
    251L, 252L), LIVEW = c(0.337, 0.471, 0.238, 0.772, 0.178, 
    0.416, 0.535, 0.356, 0.442, 0.663, 0.442, 0.497, 0.276, 0.032, 
    0.828, 0.035, 0.011, 1.224, 1.025, 0.072), SPECIES = structure(c(7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("Albacore Tuna", "Bigeye Tuna", 
    "Bluefin Tuna", "Mako", "Porbeagle", "Shark, UNSP", "Swordfish", 
    "Tuna, UNSP", "White Marlin", "Yellowfin Tuna"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("LATITUDE", 
"LONGITUDE", "LANDEDDATE", "sppCODE", "LIVEW", "SPECIES"), row.names = c(19L, 
20L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is what I've done so far but I can't figure out the rest.

```
    df2$setID<-"NA" #I created an empty setID.
    > head(df2)
   LATITUDE LONGITUDE LANDEDDATE sppCODE LIVEW   SPECIES setID
19    43.35  -60.6163 2000-08-02     251 0.337 Swordfish    NA
20    43.35  -60.6165 2000-08-02     251 0.471 Swordfish    NA
13    43.35  -60.7167 2000-08-14     251 0.238 Swordfish    NA
14    43.35  -60.7166 2000-08-14     251 0.772 Swordfish    NA
15    43.35  -60.7163 2000-08-14     251 0.178 Swordfish    NA
16    43.35  -60.7160 2000-08-14     251 0.416 Swordfish    NA
unique<-df2[which(!duplicated(df2[,1:3])),] #This is each entry that are NOT duplicate
unique2$setID<-1:13 # Ranked from 1:13
> head(unique) #looks like that
   LATITUDE LONGITUDE LANDEDDATE sppCODE LIVEW   SPECIES setID
19    43.35  -60.6163 2000-08-02     251 0.337 Swordfish     1
20    43.35  -60.6165 2000-08-02     251 0.471 Swordfish     2
13    43.35  -60.7167 2000-08-14     251 0.238 Swordfish     3
14    43.35  -60.7166 2000-08-14     251 0.772 Swordfish     4
15    43.35  -60.7163 2000-08-14     251 0.178 Swordfish     5
16    43.35  -60.7160 2000-08-14     251 0.416 Swordfish     6
rep<-df2[which(duplicated(df2[,1:3])),] #This is all my replicates
```

I need to allocate the setID of my unique dataframe to the corresponding sets (replicates with same LAT/LONG and LANDEDDATE) in the rep dataframe. Any advices would be appreciated!

Comment: I see you have solutions being posed. Don't forget about the fact that your LAT and LONG are floating point numbers. You may need to round to an appropriate level of precision _before_the_interaction_operation_ if you are hoping to test later for "sameness".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That sounds like a lot of wrangling!

Why not create a "key" with something like `paste`

```
paste(df2$LONGITUDE, df2$LATITUDE, df2$LANDEDDATE)
```

then you can use `factor` and coerce it back to its underlying integers:

```
df2$setID <- as.integer(factor(paste(df2$LONGITUDE, df2$LATITUDE, df2$LANDEDDATE)))
```

You could also do this with `data.table` if your data is large (or even if its not!).

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- data.table(df2, key=c('LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE', 'LANDEDDATE'))

df2[, setID := (.GRP), by=c('LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE', 'LANDEDDATE')]
```

Comment: `interaction` with `drop=TRUE` cuts out the `paste`-`factor` step.

Comment: Thank you all! I tend to master the art of making things more complicated than they have to be.. :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `interaction`

```
within(df2, {id = interaction(LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,LANDEDDATE)})
  LATITUDE LONGITUDE LANDEDDATE sppCODE LIVEW   SPECIES                        id
19    43.35  -60.6163 2000-08-02     251 0.337 Swordfish 43.35.-60.6163.2000-08-02
20    43.35  -60.6165 2000-08-02     251 0.471 Swordfish 43.35.-60.6165.2000-08-02
13    43.35  -60.7167 2000-08-14     251 0.238 Swordfish 43.35.-60.7167.2000-08-14
14    43.35  -60.7166 2000-08-14     251 0.772 Swordfish 43.35.-60.7166.2000-08-14
15    43.35  -60.7163 2000-08-14     251 0.178 Swordfish 43.35.-60.7163.2000-08-14
.......
```

**EDIT** add drop =TRUE option(more efficient)(@Matthew comment) , and change separator(smarter)

```
res1 <- within(df2, {id = interaction(
                           sprintf("%5.2f", LATITUDE),
                           sprintf("%5.2f", LONGITUDE),
                           LANDEDDATE,drop=TRUE,sep=':')})

res1
   LATITUDE LONGITUDE LANDEDDATE sppCODE LIVEW   SPECIES                      id
19  43.3500  -60.6163 2000-08-02     251 0.337 Swordfish 43.35:-60.62:2000-08-02
20  43.3500  -60.6165 2000-08-02     251 0.471 Swordfish 43.35:-60.62:2000-08-02
13  43.3500  -60.7167 2000-08-14     251 0.238 Swordfish 43.35:-60.72:2000-08-14
14  43.3500  -60.7166 2000-08-14     251 0.772 Swordfish 43.35:-60.72:2000-08-14
15  43.3500  -60.7163 2000-08-14     251 0.178 Swordfish 43.35:-60.72:2000-08-14
16  43.3500  -60.7160 2000-08-14     251 0.416 Swordfish 43.35:-60.72:2000-08-14
17  43.3500  -60.7169 2000-08-14     251 0.535 Swordfish 43.35:-60.72:2000-08-14
18  43.3500  -60.7166 2000-08-14     251 0.356 Swordfish 43.35:-60.72:2000-08-14
6   43.5166  -59.9169 2000-08-23     251 0.442 Swordfish 43.52:-59.92:2000-08-23
7   43.5166  -59.9168 2000-08-23     251 0.663 Swordfish 43.52:-59.92:2000-08-23
```

Comment: Notice the irregular rounding? You might want to do something about that.

Comment: @Dwin you are right. i will opte for something like `round_any` but far from my pc to do it now. feel free to edit my answer please.

Comment: As a alternative to `round_any`, you can replace `LATITUDE` with `sprintf("%5.2f", LATITUDE)` and `LONGITUDE` with `sprintf("%8.4f", LONGITUDE)` inside the `interaction`.

Comment: @Dwin I update my solution using `sprintf`. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The `id` function in `plyr` is designed to do this as efficiently as possible:

```
library(plyr)
id(df2[c("LATITUDE", "LONGITUDE", "LANDEDDATE")])
id(df2[c("LATITUDE", "LONGITUDE", "LANDEDDATE")], drop = TRUE)
```

It has the property if you then order the data frame by that variable it will be in the same order if you'd ordered it by lat, log and date.

Here's a little benchmark, not that it's likely to make much difference unless your real data is much larger than this:

```
library(microbenchmark)
df3 <- df2[c("LATITUDE", "LONGITUDE", "LANDEDDATE")]

microbenchmark(
  id(df3),
  id(df3, drop = TRUE),
  interaction(df3),
  interaction(df3, drop = TRUE))
# Unit: microseconds
#                          expr  min   lq median   uq  max neval
#                       id(df3)  366  386    397  412  575   100
#          id(df3, drop = TRUE)  421  443    460  476 1823   100
#              interaction(df3)  622  657    672  698  987   100
# interaction(df3, drop = TRUE) 1006 1053   1079 1108 2210   100
```